# Sending email as HTML from RichText Box

Tags: vb.net

I have a vb.net application with a richtext box that the email body is typed into

i then send the email and have included this code:

```
e_mail.IsBodyHtml = True
e_mail.Body = emailmessage
```

`emailmessage` being the `richtextbox.text`

but its just sending as plain text

Comment: you'd have to write your own routine to "HTML-ize" the text in the textbox. The properties you set say that the email should show HTML, but the email client can't do that if there is no HTML to render.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's sending as plain text I'm guessing because it's pulling plain text out of the RichTextBox.Text property.  The Text property has the unformatted text of the control.  The Rtf property has the rich text version (put a link in it, then message box the RichTextBox.Rtf and you'll see all the RTF codes).

If you want HTML out of that you're going to have to convert the RTF to HTML then put that in the mail object like you did.

If you're using WPF and XAML's RichTextBox this link may help:

- http://matthewmanela.com/blog/converting-rtf-to-html/

If you don't mind using Word (albeit this is hacky), you can load the RTF in Word through code and then save it as HTML (see thread below for that).

- http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?8168-How-to-convert-contents-of-Rich-Text-Box-To-HTML

You could also look for open source controls to replace the RichTextBox with something that creates the HTML itself and forget the RichTextBox (see next link):

- https://winformhtmltextbox.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Screenshots&referringTitle=Home

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
e_mail.BodyFormat = MailFormat.html
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mail.mailmessage.bodyformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: 'BodyFormat' is not a member of 'System.Net.Mail.MailMessage

Comment: Check your mail client. Some clients convert HTML to text and make the user decide to use HTML. (I know Outlook is notorious for doing this)

Comment: i have viewed the source of the email and its totally blank. this error is showing in vb.net

Answer (score 0):

If Microsoft Outlook is an option (assuming Outlook is running):

```
    Dim OutlookObject As Outlook.Application = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Dim omsg As Outlook.MailItem = OutlookObject.CreateItem(0)
    omsg.BodyFormat = Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML
    rtbMain.SelectAll()
    rtbMain.Copy()
    DirectCast(omsg.GetInspector.WordEditor, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document).Range(0, 0).PasteAndFormat(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdRecoveryType.wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
    omsg.Display()
    omsg.Send()
```